Why does the following C code enter an infinite loop?
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    for (char c=0; c<128; c++) {
        printf("%c", c);
    }
}

The output of the code prints the whole character list over and over again.
But I also tried running this code:
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    for (char c=0; c<127; c++) {
        printf("%c", c);
    }
}

The only change being the condition. It now runs fine without entering an infinite loop.
What is the reason for this?

char is signed on your system and it's max value is 127. So the condition c<128 is always true. Also you are likely getting warnings from the compiler about the same.

I guess you can change char to unsigned char and it will work. Not sure if it's acceptable to your case.

In this case, it might be instructive to use %d in the format string.

Always enable your compiler's warnings! With gcc, I use -Wall -Wextra -pedantic

@Peter-ReinstateMonica: There is no overflow. c++ is defined to operate like c = c+1, except that the lvalue is evaluated only once. c+1 is specified to apply the usual arithmetic conversions, which promote the char c to int. Then the addition is performed in int arithmetic, which produces 128 without overflowing. Then the = is performed, which is specified to convert the value to the type of its left operand, char. This conversion is implementation-defined.

@EricPostpischil Ah, interesting! Thanks. I deleted my comment. I suggest you leave yours in place; it is an interesting piece of information.

Is char signed or unsigned by default?

In C, it is implementation-defined if the char type behaves like signed char or unsigned char. If it behaves like signed char, it can only hold values between -128 to 127 inclusive. Your for loop tries to go to 128, but because char can only hold up to 127, it will never reach 128.
The condition validation checks if c < 128, and stops when c == 128. When c = 127, the loop progresses making c + 1 = -128. So it loops again and again, and never stops because it never reaches 128.
Your second loop stops at 127 because the char structure can hold up to 127, so the condition is fulfilled and the loop ends.

on 2's complement it's -128 to 127.

I'd replace "In C, the char structure can only hold values between -128 to 127" with "It's very common that a char can only ..." since C doesn't require a char to only be able to hold -128 to 127. It's the range in most implementations though.

char is not a structure. Structures are specific things in C, a sequence of member objects. char is a type, and an instance of a char is a char object.

Re “When c = 127, the loop progresses making c + 1 = -128”: This is likely what happened on OP’s system, but it should be noted the arithmetic is performed with the int type, so 127 is incremented to 128, and this is converted back to the char type. This conversion is implementation-defined, so it may produce −128, but a C implementation may also define it to produce other values, such as 127 (clamping instead of wrapping) or to produce a signal.

It seems in your system the type char behaves as the type signed char. (Note: the type char can behave either as the type signed char or unsigned char depending on compiler options.) The maximum positive value for this type is 127.  You can check this with this simple program:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main( void )
{
    printf( "SCHAR_MAX = %d\n", SCHAR_MAX );
}

So in the first loop when c is equal to 127 then the expression c++ results in overflow of the value stored in c. So the first loop becomes infinite.
If you want to output all characters in the range [0, SCHAR_MAX] you can use for example do while loop
char c = 0;
do
{
    printf( "%x", c );
} while ( c++ != SCHAR_MAX );

Pay attention to that not all characters in this range have a grapgic representation.
